# SQL How to get multiple values into one column (MS SQL)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have the following Tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE #table1
    (Batchnumber INT NOT NULL,
     BOXID       TINYINT NOT NULL,
     ErrorID     TINYINT NULL,
     Weight      INT);

    CREATE TABLE #table2
    (ErrorID     TINYINT,
     Description VARCHAR(100));

    INSERT INTO #table1(Batchnumber, BOXID, ErrorID, Weight)
    VALUES (12345, 1, NULL, 1000),
    (12345, 2, 1, 1000),
    (12345, 3, 2, 1000);

    INSERT INTO #table2
    (ErrorID, Description)
    VALUES (1, 'Network Error'),
    (2, 'Keyboard to chair interface problem'),
    (3, 'Unknown Error');
```

I need to have the following in the temp table

```
TempTable
Batchnumber | Weight | Remarks
12345         3000     Network Error, Keyboard to chair interface problem
```

So he needs only 1 row with the Batchnumber, the sum of the weight for all 3 records and 1 field with all the error codes explained

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FOR XML PATH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) solution for creating csv from rows tend to be the most common for 2016 and lower.

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT one.Batchnumber,
                one.Weight,
                two.Description
         FROM #table1 AS one
         LEFT OUTER JOIN #table2 AS two
              ON one.ErrorID = two.ErrorID)

SELECT Batchnumber,  SUM(Weight),
            STUFF((SELECT ',' + inr.Description
         FROM cte AS inr
         WHERE outr.Batchnumber = inr.Batchnumber FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
     ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, SPACE(0))
FROM cte AS outr
GROUP BY Batchnumber;
```

In 2017 there is the [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function which makes this easier.

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT one.Batchnumber,
                one.Weight,
                two.Description
         FROM #table1 AS one
         LEFT OUTER JOIN #table2 AS two
              ON one.ErrorID = two.ErrorID)

SELECT  Batchnumber,SUM(Weight),STRING_AGG(Description,',')
FROM    cte
group by Batchnumber;
```